# Using IF statement after a WITH clause

Tags: t-sql

I want to create an alias for a SELECT statement, but then I want to limit the resultset with a TOP clause. If the procedure TopCount parameter is bigger than 0, I want to put limit result set with TOP clause.

But after the WITH clause, the IF statement is producing an error. Can I continue with IF or different than the SELECT statement after the WITH clause?

```
WITH
   alias AS (...)
IF @TopCount>0
   SELECT TOP (@TopCount) * FROM alias;
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM alias;
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Your best bet would be to give your top variable a very high default value.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.if_branch (@top INT = 2147483647)
AS 
BEGIN

WITH d AS 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.databases AS ds
        WHERE ds.name = 'tempdb'
    )
SELECT TOP (@top) *
FROM d;

END
```

Comment: Can you use a BIGINT here? We have tables too large for INT max.

Comment: @Joshua yes, but is anyone really selecting that many rows? What would a person conceivably do with all that, unless it's a data export?

Comment: Indeed; when I asked for all the rows I didn't want only the first 4 billion.

Answer (score 2):

`WITH` declares a CTE, which is something you can use in just **1 statement** (like a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc.).

An `IF` is a control flow mechanic that separates statements (or blocks of statements) so you can't declare a CTE and conditionally refer to it on multiple statements.

You can try setting the `@TopCount` value to a high enough number before the `SELECT`.

```
IF @TopCount IS NULL OR @TopCount < 1
    SET @TopCount = POWER(2, 30) -- A big enough number (careful with overflows!)

WITH
   alias AS (...)
SELECT TOP (@TopCount) * FROM alias;
```

Comment: you may want to use `CONVERT(int, POWER(2.0, 31) - 1)`, or just the maximum value for an int, which is `2147483647`

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. @sp_BlitzErik's answer is fit for clear to understand. It isn't checking topCount is greated than 0 in every execution. It isn't calculating limit of int type. Again thank you for your answer and I learnt POWER with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The TOP parameter is an expression, not a literal. Try to use:

```
WITH alias
  AS (...)
SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN @TopCount>0 THEN @TopCount ELSE 2147483647 END) *
  FROM alias;
```

PS.: I have not tested this trick with a variable, but the TOP parameter obtained from a subquery works perfectly.

PPS.: I tested with a user variable. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your calculation beforehand in a case statement.

I've declared `@topcount` in this statement for ease of testing, but so you can set it and test it:

```
declare @TopCount int

SELECT
    @TopCount = CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(@TopCount,0) > 0
            THEN @TopCount
            ELSE count(1) END
    FROM alias

select top (@TopCount) *
from alias
```

You can use the final select in a with statement if you need it for a [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) from here quite easily.